# Kotlin Data class setter using class fields

Tags: kotlin, data-class

I have a redis entity using a **kotlin data class** and its **Id** should be a combination of few other fields from the same class. 
Can this be achieved by defining setter for Id field instead of computing it outside of data class?

```
@RedisHash("Game")
data class Game(
  @Id
  val generatedId: String = "Default_ID",
  val name: String,
  val location: String,
  val homeTeam: String,
  val awayTeam: String

)

// want something like this

var generatedId : String = "DEFAULT_ID"
  get() = "${name}${location}"

// or even better

var generated_Id : String =  "${name}${location}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to do something like this?

```
@RedisHash("Game")
data class Game(
    val name: String,
    val location: String,
    val homeTeam: String,
    val awayTeam: String,
    @Id
    val generatedId: String = "${name}${location}"
)
```

Comment: thanks a ton, I was sure I was missing something basic there .. it was a matter of moving generated after both name and location :-).

Comment: a followup question is there a way I can restrict setting this value from outside? I imagine writing a setter that throws an exception?